# ¿"Binding" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, informática

Con frecuencia oigo la palabra inglesa *binding* y no consigo encontrarle una traducción solvente en castellano (quizá porque no acabo de entender el significado exacto).

Como me temo que puede tener muchos posibles significados dependiendo del contexto, me centraré en la usada en el mundo de la programación.

Leo pues en [Wikipedia - Binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding):

> Data binding, the technique of connecting two data elements together

Y luego en [Wikipedia - Language binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding):

> In computing, a binding from a programming language to a library or
>   operating system service is an application programming interface (API)
>   providing glue code to use that library or service in a particular
>   programming language.

En este caso entiendo que binding podría traducirse como una "capa" o incluso "ligazón" o "extensión" con la aplicación original para facilitar su uso.

¿Es esta traducción válida? ¿Qué otras palabras podrían traducir este significado?

Comment: En esas circunstancias yo suelo utilizar "enlazado"

Comment: Significa unir, enlazar, crear una conexión entre dos partes.

Comment: Yo usaría "Vincular".

Comment: Enlazar o vincular dependiendo del contexto

Comment: En programación enlazar se suele asociar mas con linking, que no es lo mismo que binding.

Comment: "binding" significa "permanente" cuando usado en referencia a la ley

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu pregunta mencionas dos significados de `binding`.

Veamos el primero: `Binding` como en `Data binding`, significa generalmente enlazar o asociar dos variables, de forma que cuando una cambia la otra cambia también al nuevo valor. Yo traduciría por `enlazado de datos`.

Segundo caso: `Binding` como en `Language binding` se refiere a un código que permite a un lenguaje de programación usar código escrito en otro lenguaje, normalmente realizando un mapeo entre las funciones del código externo y funciones propias que quedan disponibles en el lenguaje de programación al que pertenecen las `bindings`.

En este caso se podría usar `enlaces` (ya que *enlazan* un código externo con el lenguaje de programación) o `conectores`, que *conectan* un código externo con el lenguaje.

Son conceptos de programación antiguos y no recuerdo que haya una traducción ampliamente aceptada.

Comment: es decir que de alguna forma sería una especie de "plugin".

Comment: Podría entenderse, pero plugin tiene un matiz de 'enchufar y usar', suele ser más aplicado sobre componentes de un programa o sistema, de forma que una vez instalado el plugin el programa o sistema ofrece una nueva funcionalidad al usuario automáticamente. En este caso, el 'conector' ofrece más opciones pero lo hace a través del uso del lenguaje, por lo que no es tan 'directo'. Es decir, en el sentido amplio se podría considerar un plugin, pero a la hora de ser preciso yo no usaría 'plugin' por ser menos certero en su significado, lo que podría producir cierta confusión.

Comment: No me gusta mucho *enlace* porque en informática suele corresponder con el inglés *link*, que no tiene ninguna relación con *binding*. Pero *conector* o *conectar* me parecen buenas propuestas.

Comment: Enlace es la definicion perfecta.  En Computacion igualmente se refiere a la capacidad de enlazar y sincronizar datos: 1 way data binding, 2 way data binding. Asincronico y sincronico.

Comment: Yo diría es mejor adecuar la traducción según el significado a traducir y poder ser más preciso. *Enlace*, además, es una palabra ya bastante sobrecargada en el mundo de la informática.

Answer (score 3):

Recuerdo en mis clases en la Universidad (de ciencias en computadoras) que "binding" lo traducíamos con la siguiente palabra:

> Eslabonar

Definición de RAE:

> [**eslabonar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GQt11lC)
>
> 1. tr. Unir unos eslabones con otros formando cadena.
> 2. tr. Enlazar o encadenar las partes de un discurso o unas cosas con otras. U. t. c. prnl.

Answer (score 1):

Literalemente, la palabra "bind" significa atar una cosa a otra.

Por ejemplo, el Anillo Único tiene una inscripción que termina con "...One Ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them",  generalmente traducido como "Un Anillo para traerlos a todos y atarlos a las tinieblas"

Los significados técnicos que mencionaste en tu pregunta también tienen que ver con atar. "Data binding" ata dos elementos de datos juntos, y en la definición de "language binding" dice que provee algo llamado "glue code". En castellano "glue" es pegamento, que es como una atadura que en vez de cuerdas usa enlaces químicos.

Por lo tanto, en general podría decirse que la palabra "binding" en la mayoría de los casos significa lo mismo que "atadura" en castellano.

Answer (score 1):

Binding es el termino que se usa para unir dos cosas.

- *Binder*: es un portafolio que usa para poner papeles.
- *Binding*: es un proceso de computo, en donde diferentes clases o metodos se unen en un proyecto.
- *They are binding*: Cuando una pareja esta conversando y conociendo, en un proceso de enamoramiento.

Como dices, dependerá mucho del contexo en el que se utilice ya que en el ingles hay diferentes tipos de slangs (palabras criollas) que pueden derivar de esta misma.

Comment: La tercera definición que das, la unión varios métodos o clases, si es lo que creo que es en inglés se dice 'linking', y en español se traduce como 'enlazado' (al generar un ejecutable un código se compila y se enlaza, generando el fichero ejecutable final).