# ¿Cómo traducir "binding vote" al español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Acabo de publicar en Meta la pregunta [*¿Sobre qué elementos de revisión debemos evitar los mods ejercer el “**binding vote**”?*](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3044/5481), en la que explico un poco qué son los *binding votes* que tenemos los moderadores.

Es un privilegio para la moderación por el que, en lugar de esperar a tener consenso, realiza la acción. Por ejemplo: no espera a tener 5 votos para cerrar una pregunta; la puede cerrar con un único voto de moderador.

Lo mejor que se me ha ocurrido para traducirlo es "votos de decisión unilaterales", pero [unilateral](https://dle.rae.es/?id=b5mUhhw) no creo que recoja del todo las particularidades del *binding vote*. Tampoco es que sea "[inapelable](https://dle.rae.es/?id=LBE5FH6)", aunque en inglés se defina una *binding decision* como:

> *A decision that binds the parties affected by it and that they may not appeal.*

Que viene a significar más "impuesto" que "inapelable".

También se puede interpretar que *binding* tiene el sentido de atar o unir cosas juntas, pero en este caso no creo que un *binding vote* una los votos o la voluntad de los usuarios, porque precisamente se podría oponer a cualquier número de otros votos y ejercer la acción.

Podría traducirse como "[decisivo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BxPNBIF)" ya que "decide o resuelve" (primera acepción), pero dada la segunda acepción ("Que tiene consecuencias importantes") podría interpretarse como que el voto fue "importante y necesario" para realizar la acción, en lugar de "suficiente".

"Voto decisivo" es lo mejor que se me ocurre a mí, pero tal vez alguien tenga una idea o propuesta mejor.

¿Cómo traducir *binding vote* al español?

Comment: Nota, hay una pregunta preexistente: [¿“Binding” en castellano?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15534/5481), pero entiendo que el contexto de esa pregunta está reducido al ámbito informático, mientras que esta pregunta se centra en buscar un término para "binding vote", y el "_binding_" de "binding vote" puede ser el mismo o no que el de esa pregunta. A día de hoy ninguna de las respuestas de esa pregunta responde necesariamente a esta.

Comment: El uso de la palabra es raro por decir poco. *Binding* lo he visto como "vinculante", referido a referéndums por ejemplo. También cuando se habla de acuerdos (ahí significa "que obliga a las partes"). Siempre tiene que ver con partes en consenso, justamente lo contrario a lo que sugiere ese voto privilegiado del que hablas.

Comment: @pablodf76 quizá la elección de llamarlo "binding vote" por parte del equipo de StackExchange esté mal hecha para empezar. Creo que sería válido para responder a esta respuesta proponer algo que no traduzca "binding" en ninguna de sus acepciones. Podría llamarse  "supervoto", "voto todopoderoso" o "voto de la snitch dorada" :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como veo que Pablo ya ha propuesto "voto decisorio" y, en cierta manera, "voto vinculante", me gustaría aportar la tercera de las alternativas que se me habían ocurrido:

**voto de oro**

El calificativo "de oro" se aplica en ocasiones a elementos que tienen un efecto decisorio superior al habitual, como en "[gol de oro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JIGLloV)" o "[acción de oro](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0KZwLbE)".
Concretamente, para "acción de oro" la Wikipedia da [esta definición](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acci%C3%B3n_de_oro):

> La acción de oro es una acción nominal que permite a su poseedor vencer a todas las demás acciones y accionistas en una votación bajo ciertas circunstancias.

Lo cual, si sustituimos "acción" por "voto", creo que es la definición casi exacta de lo que es un *binding vote*.

Comment: ¡cierto! Recuerdo que durante un tiempo en el fútbol se utilizó el [_gol de oro_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gol_de_oro), que daba la victoria inmediata a quien lo lograra.

Answer (score 8):

Siguiendo la sugerencia de Diego, me propongo traducir *binding vote* sin respetar la traducción habitual de la palabra inglesa *binding* en un contexto similar, que es *vinculante* (por ejemplo: *[binding referendum](https://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/binding+referendum.html)* = "consulta vinculante"), con el significado de "que obliga a ejecutar la voluntad expresada o el consenso alcanzado", aun cuando *vincular* no tenga realmente relación con *obligar*.

El verbo inglés *bind* significa tanto "unir, enlazar" como "atar, sujetar". Aquí es fácil ver la relación. Creo que la idea de llamarle *binding vote* a este supervoto de los moderadores tiene que ver con la segunda acepción. Algo que es *binding* está "atado" y no puede moverse. Quien propuso este nombre debe haber priorizado esta idea (que el voto de un moderador no puede ser anulado por los usuarios) antes que la que menciona Diego (que el voto de un moderador basta para hacer algo que requeriría el acuerdo de varios usuarios). Esta acepción aparece en un famoso pasaje de la Biblia (Mt 16:19):

> And I will give unto thee the keys of the kingdom of heaven: and
>   whatsoever thou shalt bind on earth shall be bound in heaven: and
>   whatsoever thou shalt loose on earth shall be loosed in heaven.

En castellano:

> Y a ti te daré las llaves del reino de los cielos; y todo lo que
>   atares en la tierra será atado en los cielos; y todo lo que desatares
>   en la tierra será desatado en los cielos.

Apuntando a las susodichas llaves, una posibilidad sería traducir *binding vote* como ***voto de cierre*** (aunque esto podría confundirse con el voto para cerrar [*close*] una pregunta). ***Voto decisivo*** no me suena del todo bien, porque tiene otros matices (como indica Diego); en su lugar propondría ***voto [decisorio](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BxRKuuP)***, que suena más "legal" y tiene una única acepción. Cabe también quedarse con una opción más sencilla y llamarlo ***supervoto***.

Si vamos al caso, en realidad, este "voto" no es tanto un voto como una decisión directa, pero no se me ocurre otra palabra que transmita mejor la idea (¿***acción decisoria*** tal vez?).

Comment: Me quito el sombrero, qué respuesta tan buena

Comment: Me gusta más **supervoto** que _voto de oro_ +1

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya has elegido mejor respuesta, voy con mi sugerencia. Me ha costado un poco, pero me ha venido a la cabeza la siguiente expresión: **voto de gracia**. Sabía que existía alguna expresión para "cuando uno llega y se acaba la discusión" jeje. Por analogía con expresiones similares, creo que es buena:

> **Tiro de gracia** (RAE)
>
> 1. m. tiro que se da en la cabeza para rematar a quien ha sido fusilado.
> 2. m. Acción que pone fin inexorablemente a un determinado proceso o situación. La caída de la bolsa supuso para él el tiro de gracia.

Especial atención a la segunda acepción. Creo que se ajusta bastante.

También existe

> Golpe de gracia
>
> 1. m. golpe con que se remata a alguien.
> 2. m. Revés que completa la desgracia o la ruina de alguien o de algo.

Comment: La verdad es que es motivo de debate si el no asignar el galardón de mejor respuesta anima a que se publiquen respuestas adicionales. En cualquier caso, ese voto siempre se puede cambiar y actualizar a una respuesta más reciente si mejora la "mejor respuesta" ya existente. "Voto de gracia" es una excelente respuesta. Ahí anda junto a "voto de oro". Son muy parecidas. Creo que sigo prefiriendo "de oro" por las connotaciones de "superior", frente a "de gracia", pero esta propuesta es también bastante buena.